# Get a user submitted hour-minute time ===> Change it and display it

Tags: php, date, time

This i what I am trying to achieve:

1)user submits roster_input from a form (here I just set a variable as an example input)

2)php changes it into a timestamp and subtracts 7500 seconds

3)php displays the new time, but in a different timezone

obviously I am doing something terribly wrong.. But it's the first time I am dealing with dates!

```
$roster_input='14:15' ;
$timestamp = strtotime($roster_input) - 7500;

$date = new DateTime($timestamp, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date;
```

Tried also, without success:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $timestamp, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PHP Manual

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

Therefore, you are to use a valid date string:

### THIS WORKS. Returns 12:10

```
$roster_input='14:15' ;

$timestamp = strtotime($roster_input)  - 7500;

$format =  date("H:i", $timestamp );

$date = new DateTime($format, new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
    echo $date->format('H:i') . "\n"; //Note how you echo the result
```

### THIS FAILS (Using Timestamp directly as in your case);

```
$roster_input='14:15' ;

$timestamp = strtotime($roster_input)  - 7500;

$date = new DateTime($timestamp , new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
    echo $date->format('H:i') . "\n";
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::_*construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (1362417000) at position 8 (0): Unexpected character' in writecodeonline.com/php:7 Stack trace: #0 writecodeonline.com/php(7): DateTime->*_construct('1362417000', Object(DateTimeZone)) #1 {main} thrown on line 7

### TO USE TIMESTAMP DIRECTLY, THIS WORKS: returns 17:10

```
$roster_input='14:15' ;

$timestamp = strtotime($roster_input)  - 7500;

$date = new DateTime('@'.$timestamp , new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru')); //Notice '@'.
    echo $date->format('H:i') . "\n";
```

Which ever suits your target result. Just be aware of the different results
Read more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: Yes of course, the second working example is similar to this: `$date = new DateTime("@$time", new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
    echo $date->format('H:i') . "\n";` Still returns 17:10

Comment: perfect, I used option 1 to get going! Thanks :)

Comment: Wait a sec.. I thought it was correct but it's not working.. I tried to transform into 2 different timezones but it's not doing the time conversion! Maybe it required a full date instead of only HH:MM?  http://ideone.com/OdyMeL

Comment: Yes, I did mention that you should observe the time difference in the two methods. I'd advice you use a full date. The first working example converted back to a date format. The second just used timestamp and you saw the difference. So depending on your preference or expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track. The only issue is that you can't just dump out an object as a string.

Try changing the last line to this:

```
echo $date->format("c");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or for a 3-char change to your original:

```
$roster_input='14:15';
$timestamp = strtotime($roster_input) - 7500;
$date = new DateTime("@$timestamp", new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format(DATE_RFC822);
```